# Using BookBlock jquery plugin for the Navigation for Div contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bookblock

I am using Bookblock jQuery plugin as a transition effect between divs (consists of image and text) whenever the user clicks the link on the navigation bar.

Somehow, when the nav is at the top of the div, the links won't work.

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="bb-custom-grid" id="bb-custom-grid">
     <li> 
      <ul id="services-submenu">
       <li class="bb-current">Page 1</li>
       <li>Page 2</li>
       <li>Page 3</li>
       <li>Page 4</li>
       <li>Page 5</li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="bb-bookblock">
           <div class="bb-item">
          <div>
                    <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
                  </div>
       </div>
       <div class="bb-item">
          <div>
                    <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
                  </div>
       </div>
              <div class="bb-item">
          <div>
                    <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
                  </div>
       </div>
              <div class="bb-item">
          <div>
                    <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
                  </div>
       </div>
              <div class="bb-item">
          <div>
                    <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
                  </div>
       </div>
           </div>
           </li>
           </ul>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class for next, and previous in your

```
<li class="next"></li><li class="previous"></li>
```

to render from page 1 to page 5.

Example:

```
<ul class="services-submen" >
    <li class="previous">
        <a id="bb-nav-prev" data-toggle="popover"  href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <a id="bb-nav-next"data-toggle="popover"  href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```